# Flask test client doesn't have as_tuple argument

Tags: python, flask

I am a bit confused on this error I am getting. I am writing a test to make sure I can get a 2xx status code

```
import unittest
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

class FlaskTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_index(self):
        tester = app.test_client(self)
        response = tester.get("/")
        status_code = response.status_code
        self.assertEqual(status_code,200)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

My error

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_index (__main__.FlaskTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Downloads/test_cases.py", line 9, in test_index
    response = tester.get("/")
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 1135, in get
    return self.open(*args, **kw)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/testing.py", line 216, in open
    return super().open(  # type: ignore
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 1082, in open
    builder = EnvironBuilder(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'as_tuple'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.002s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Not sure what this error means if someone can help me out

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading Flask fixed this issue

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).